# Ubuntu 22.04 crashes on wake from suspend

Tags: suspend, crash, 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04 have been crashing on wake from suspend. The mouse and keyboard stop responding,so I do a hard reboot. I tried unplugging the HDMI (or USB-C Dell dock-in station) before clicking suspend, it didn't work.

I am unsure whether is it a bug or something else, I included a screenshot of the "important" logs.

Thanks you!

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq2pR.jpg